Difference between "have (got) your hands full" and "be run/rushed off your feet"
Are there any differences in the meaning of or when we use the idioms 'have (got) your hands full' and 'be run/rushed off your feet'? The definitions in the Cambridge Dictionary are:

have (got) your hands full: to be very busy or involved with something
be run/rushed off your feet: to be extremely busy


They describe being very busy from two slightly different perspectives - having a lot of things to cope with (metaphorically, trying not to drop any of the things you are carrying) or having to hurry from one task to another.

I'm actually surprised at the definition of "have (got) your hands full". In use, it doesn't mean the same kind of 'busy' as "rushed off your feet".
"Rushed off your feet" is something you might say about someone on a busy shift at their job. If a restaurant had more customers than usual, you might say the waitress is "rushed off her feet". Rushed is related to speed - having to do something fast, or hurriedly, like the waitress taking orders in that busy restaurant quickly so she can move to the next table.
Saying someone "has their hands full" usually means that they are at capacity with something. Speed or haste could be the answer to the problem, but it isn't implied in the saying. Imagine someone with their literal hands full - they can carry what they have (just) but they can't take any more on. The context in which I hear it the most is when parents have a lot of children - eg "with 5 kids they certainly have their hands full!". It is also sometimes said of a 'challenging' child (somewhat unkindly) that "they are a handful", meaning they create enough work for their parents not to be able to cope with any more.
The kind of contexts in which you would say a person is rushed off their feet tend to be temporary. A work shift will end. But contexts in which you would say a person has their hands full tend to be longer lasting - when a person has a load of responsibility that they are figuratively carrying, such as having children, or a very responsible job.
